# HTTP 404 Java Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, http-status-code-404

I get this error when I click on submit

```
HTTP Status 404 - /GradeRetrieval/DbConnection
type Status report
message /GradeRetrieval/DbConnection
description The requested resource is not available.
```

This is the form tag, my HTML form has a submit button.

```
<form action="../DbConnection" method="post">
```

This is my directory structure
[image: Directory structure]

This is my webxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>GradeRetreival</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>DbConnection</display-name>
<servlet-name>DbConnection</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>DbConnection</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DbConnection</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>DbConnection</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Kindly help.

Comment: what is in your dbconnection class?

is the url form submit correct?

does your dbconnection accept post method?

p.s: connecting to db from controller????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, the servlet name needs to be fully specified:

```
<servlet-class>action.DbConnection</servlet-class>
```

Also, make sure your `url-pattern` is correct.

Comment: You are correct - and assuming this is the root of this problem, it is worthy to note that this will have produced an exception stacktrace in the server log files so its always a good idea to look there first.